# Escaping braces with regexp in the middle of a string

Tags: regex, tcl

I want to write a regular expression in tcl that can detect the presence of curly braces (`{`,`}`) in middle of a string and replace it with a backslash.

For example  i/p:

```
designs/abc/def {/designs/abc/def/abc{123}defg} {abc/sed/123erf} -conect abc
```

o/p:

```
designs/abc/def {/designs/abc/def/abc\{123\}defg} {abc/sed/123erf} -conect abc
```

Comment: Why are the other `{` and `}` not replaced?

Comment: Presumably because they're preceded/followed by whitespace.

Comment: only curly braces having a character(anything but not space) on its Left and right should get preceded by a backslash

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that only braces surrounded by characters on both sides should be replaced, then I think that you need word boundaries:

```
% set input "designs/abc/def {/designs/abc/def/abc{123}defg} {abc/sed/123erf} -conect abc"
designs/abc/def {/designs/abc/def/abc{123}defg} {abc/sed/123erf} -conect abc
% regsub -all {\y[{}]\y} $input {\\\0} result
2
% puts $result
designs/abc/def {/designs/abc/def/abc\{123\}defg} {abc/sed/123erf} -conect abc
```

In Tcl, `\y` matches between `\w` and `\W`, that is between a word and a non-word character or between a word character and the beginning/end of string.

The replace of `\\\0` gives a backslash and the matched string.

---

In case you can also have braces escaped at the beginning/end of string, you'll need something a bit different:

```
% set input "{/designs/abc/def/abc{123}defg}"
{/designs/abc/def/abc{123}defg}
% regsub -all {(?:\y|^)[{}](?:\y|$)} $input {\\\0} result
4
% puts $result
\{/designs/abc/def/abc\{123\}defg\}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can use lookaround to make that elegant, but you can fake it by including part of the match in the output: replace `(\S)([{}])(\S)` by `\1\\\2\3`.

Comment: Tcl's RE engine doesn't implement lookbehind at all.

Comment: Hence »usually« (as in: in other engines).